# how can i connect openam7 with mysql in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, openam

I cant successfully connect my openam7 with mysql in ubuntu 22.04

The detailed steps to configure mysql with openam7 in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Generally these type of requests don't do well on Stack, people, myself included, like seeing what someone tried and which part of their process isn't working. But count yourself lucky that I recently had to do this and I've got the steps on hand. So without knowing where you got stuck I'm just going to give all the steps that worked for me.

But if you do get stuck after this, be sure to share what you tried, where you got stuck, and if you have any error codes share them also. Then the community will happily help you.

Good luck!

**Create a MySQL database for OpenAM to use**

> mysql -u root -p
> CREATE DATABASE openam;

**Create a MySQL user for OpenAM to use**

> CREATE USER 'openamuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON openam.* TO 'openamuser'@'localhost';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

**Download and install OpenAM7 on Ubuntu 22.04**

> ```
> wget https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/releases/download/7.0.0/XUI-7.0.0.war
> sudo mv XUI-7.0.0.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/openam.war
> ```

**Configure OpenAM7 to use the MySQL database**

> sudo nano /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/openam.xml

**Replace the existing  element with the following**

> 

**Restart the Tomcat service**

> sudo service tomcat8 restart

Comment: The Element replacement didn't come through entirely...

Comment: <Resource name="jdbc/openam"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openam?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
          username="openamuser"
          password="password"
          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="30"
          maxWait="10000"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          logAbandoned="true"/>